# How to count the number of <li> returned through ajax using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a ajax code which returns the list items as

```
<li>one</li>
<li>Two</li>
```

Each time it will return different number of `<li>`'s. I want to check the number of `<li>` it returns. How to check it using JavaScript.

Comment: Are you trying to count the line item tags without attaching the returned HTML to the DOM? if you are, your easiest solution will be jQuery based, as most DOM methods ( ie. getElementsByTagNmae ) don't work on document fragments.

Comment: Yes I am trying to count <li>'s which ajax retuns, before adding it to DOM

Comment: Is using jQuery to do it out of the question? If not, it would be as simple as `$(returnedHTML).find('li').length`

Comment: @ERIK Great Works Perfectly!.  Please add this comment as answer. I will tick it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here ya go:

```
$(returnedHTML).find('li').length
```

This takes the returnedHTML and only counts the line items within it.

Comment: @sparr it absolutely will not. [From the manual](http://api.jquery.com/find/): `the method accepts a selector expression of the same type that we can pass to the $() function. The elements will be filtered by testing whether they match this selector.`

Comment: deleted my comment, was thinking of a different function

Comment: This will work if his lis have a container in the returnedHTML, which is barely the case when you make an ajax request to append the lis in an already existing ul.

Answer (score 3):

`ajaxHtml.split('<li').length - 1` for counting the raw ajax html.

Or, `element.getElementsByTagName("li").length` (with `element` being a parent container for the `LI` tags.)

Comment: I have <li> items in normal html page too. I need only the no if <li>'s ajax page returning

Comment: He wants to check the # of li tags returned from an AJAX request -- probably before the elements are added to the DOM. Your answer counts the total `li` tags on the entire page.

Comment: Did my job. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
var count = elements.length;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to look within a specific list, jQuery makes it simple:

$("DIV_NAME > ul > li").length

Answer (score 0):

If the list you want to test is coming in as a string from an AJAX request, you'll just treat it like a string, instead of a set of DOM objects.

Take a look at this bit of code.

```
var input = "<li>one</li><li>Two</li>";
var pattern = /<li>/gi;

var match;
var count = 0;
while(match = pattern.exec(input)) {
    count++;
}

alert("There are "+count+" occurences of <li> in the input string.");
```

What I'm doing here is using an regular expression to find occurrences of `<li>` case insensitively (just to be certain) and globally (treat the entire string as a single block of text to be searched).

Answer (score -2):

**FIXED:** Some people thought that I am counting LIs on link click event and also not counting it from html response. Here is the edited answer.

If you got html response something like this:

**myhtml.html:**

```
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

**Then your jQuery part may be look like this:**

```
$.get('myhtml.html', function(data) {
   alert( $(data).find("li").length ); // 3
});
```

Comment: This is so unnecessarily complicated that it's not even funny.

Comment: That PHP looks like HTML to me.

Comment: @amphetamachine: But it is working and I code it to check it quickly. But your comment is so funny.

Comment: Russell Dias: I think you did not write a php file with html tags.

Comment: It is strange you are using jQuery but not really using it, `$("#ULs li").length` would do well. Either way, this ignores the AJAX part.

Comment: @Kobi: Thanks for enhancement. I used jQuery to capture the link click event.

Comment: @Naveed: No I did not write a php file with html tags.

Comment: I never said it didn't work mate =) I was merely joking about the PHP being HTML.