# How to get number of elements returned from ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697957/how-to-count-the-number-of-li-returned-through-ajax-using-javascript?answertab=votes#tab-top) approach for getting number of `li` returned from ajax call:

```
$.post('@Url.Action("actionName", "controller")', function (data) {

     $('#notificationCounter').html($(data).find('li').length);

});
```

The result looks like below:

```
<li>
        <a href="#">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <img src="/Content/Images/UserPhotos/nofile.png" alt="profile">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-8 new-class">
                    <span>...</span>
                    <div>
                        <span>..</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
</li>
<li>
        <a href="#">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <img src="/Content/Images/UserPhotos/nofile.png" alt="profile">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-8 new-class">
                    <span>...</span>
                    <div>
                        <span>..</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
</li>
```

For example for that result I should get 2 because the result returned two `li`, But I get 0!
Any idea?

Comment: Did you try to check a length of data that returned by ajax call?? Something like console.log(data.length);

Comment: @Sirwan Afifi print the return of the ajax call

Comment: @OliSoproniB. As I mentioned I get the result (those lis in my question) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find) looks for *descendant* elements, but your `li` elements are the top level of the jQuery set you're creating.

You can add those by using `filter("li").length`:

```
var elements = $(data);
$('#notificationCounter').html(
    elements.filter('li').length + elements.find('li').length
);
```

Or just use `.filter` without `.find` if you don't want to count descendant `li` elements (there aren't any in your HTML example).

Gratuitous live example:

```js
var data = 
    '<li>' +
    '        <a href="#">' +
    '            <div class="row">' +
    '                <div class="col-xs-4">' +
    '                    <img src="/Content/Images/UserPhotos/nofile.png" alt="profile">' +
    '                </div>' +
    '                <div class="col-xs-8 new-class">' +
    '                    <span>...</span>' +
    '                    <div>' +
    '                        <span>..</span>' +
    '                    </div>' +
    '                </div>' +
    '            </div>' +
    '        </a>' +
    '</li>' +
    '<li>' +
    '        <a href="#">' +
    '            <div class="row">' +
    '                <div class="col-xs-4">' +
    '                    <img src="/Content/Images/UserPhotos/nofile.png" alt="profile">' +
    '                </div>' +
    '                <div class="col-xs-8 new-class">' +
    '                    <span>...</span>' +
    '                    <div>' +
    '                        <span>..</span>' +
    '                    </div>' +
    '                </div>' +
    '            </div>' +
    '        </a>' +
    '</li>';
    var elements = $(data);
    $('#notificationCounter').html(
        ".filter plus .find: " +
        (elements.filter('li').length + elements.find('li').length) +
        "<br>.filter alone: " +
        elements.filter('li').length
    );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="notificationCounter"></div>
```

Comment: Great. Thanks I didn't know that. I'm waiting to mark your solution as answer. :) Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
$('#notificationCounter').html($(data).length);
```

Because list-items are top-level elements in your result, simply check the length of the jquery object which holds your data.

Answer (score -2):

Oh, I'm late :( same answer: http://jsfiddle.net/dz1cz9nm/

HTML data for the test code:

```
<div id="datastore">
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <img src="/Content/Images/UserPhotos/nofile.png" alt="profile" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-8 new-class">
                    <span>...</span>
                    <div>
                        <span>..</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
</li>
<li>
        <a href="#">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <img src="/Content/Images/UserPhotos/nofile.png" alt="profile" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-8 new-class">
                    <span>...</span>
                    <div>
                        <span>..</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
</div>
```

Javscript code:

```
var data = $("#datastore").html();
alert($(data).filter('li').length + $(data).find('li').length)
```

At least I hope that link and code will help you to debug future code as you can test it online :)

Comment: Thanks to whoever who voted me negatively. I think my time has not been uselessly spent.